# How to merge folder-based branches within the same SVN repository?

Tags: svn

I've inherited an SVN repository with the following structure:

```
Master
-TheCodeRepo // Application code repo in here
Branches
-CoderGuy1
--Ticket123
---TheCodeRepo // Application code repo in here
-CoderGuy2
--Ticket555
---TheCodeRepo // Application code repo in here
-CoderGuy3
--Ticket444
---TheCodeRepo // Application code repo in here
```

I need to merge all these 'branches' into the master repository. Its a complete mess. Is this even possible? Or will I have to use some diff GUI and manually merge everything?

Answer (score 0):

It looks for me like the usage of the feature branch strategy, with some extra directory per developer. If you look at the [documentation in the SVN Red Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.feature), you will see there the following pattern:

1. Ensure for each feature branch, that it is current, by merging the changes on the Master branch to the feature branch.
2. Then do finally a reintegrate, and delete the feature branch after that.
3. Repeat these 2 steps for each feature branch.

A new policy should of course avoid the feature branches for most bugs, and just fix them on the release branch (you should have one), or directly on the Master (normally called trunk).

Comment: "should of course avoid the feature branches" ?! **REALLY?!** I think, **you must doesn't promote** bad work-style instead of good.

Comment: Personally this whole fat copy-pasta of the entire application via the 'feature branch' methodology is killing me. I want GIT goddamn it. But back on topic - mliebelt would you be able to provide commands or some vague TortoiseSVN instructions? Thing is I had tried to perform a SVN merge in various ways previously and got an error about bad ancestries.

Comment: I think that fixing bugs on the trunk (or the release branch) is more natural (in Subversion), because the errors possible and the cost of merging is way more higher than the risk introduced by fixing bugs on the trunk.